# How do i force a data Transfer/Validation in a mvvm application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have a very simple page with a few text boxes & text blocks. bound to an object's properties via xaml in a standard mvvm way.
To dismiss the page i have added an application bar with an "Ok" and a "Cancel" button.

If the user enters text in the first textbox, and taps the ok button on the application bar **without first changing focus to any other control on the page**, the value on the textbox is not transfered to the Binded object's property (e.g. the string is empty).
If however the user just selects any other control in the page before taping the ok button, then it Works fine.

It seems that for the value of the textbox to be transfered back to its bound data ítem, it needs to loose focus first, and this somehow doesnt happen as the page is dismissed from the application bar.

I recall having a very similar problem in Windows Forms applications, but there a simple call to this.Validate() before closing the form would solve it. However i see no Validate() method on the Windows phone Application Page.

So how do i "force" the data to be transfered back from the form when i dismiss the page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property on the binding, setting it to `PropertyChanged` should force the binding to update anytime the textbox text changes

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, after reading the MSDN link you provided, i see that your sugested approach would work, but for my particular scenario i found that using MyTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource(); is exactly what i wanted.
 I just set the Binding UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit on my xaml, and call the UpdateSource() as above on my ok handler.